# Best way to share answer with the community

Tags: discussion

I have recently spent some time putting together a "recipe" for getting a vagrant box up and running with clojure / emacs / nrepl. It took me a couple days to get it spot on. I'd like to share it but don't want to ask a disingenuous question that I know the answer to. Is there a standard way of "asking" a question and then supplying the answer? Is this done or should I use some other forum for this?

Comment: Three points to note. Make your question a good one. Don't just write a line. Have an actual question otherwise you'll run into problems. Secondly, it sounds like you might be about to write a book. Avoid this. Lastly, this doesn't sound like it would be on-topic for Stack Overflow. Be careful _where_ you do this.

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) might shed some light on the situation...

Comment: Thanks Ben - it sounds like a page of code / content might not be a sensible answer for this.

Comment: Okay - reading @Yannis' great answer and the link to Joel's post, I figured that it might be safe to give this a try. I guess we'll see. If you hate what I've done, let me know. [Vagrant / Clojure / Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872231/vagrant-clojure-emacs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your own questions is not only allowed, [it's encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/). You can even post the question and answer at the same time:

[image]

That said, your question should stand on its own. We won't judge it differently just because it comes with a self answer. It should be on topic, and as clear and concise as it can be. The tricky part is that we also expect you to show some prior research or effort in it, and that's not always possible with self answered questions.

Another option, if you are interested in writing a detailed blog post about your "recipe", would be the [Programmers Community blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Though it is uncommon, you are allowed to ask questions and answer them yourself. If you believe it may help others in the future (e.g. it is constructive, not too localized etc.).