# Is there a way to post a guide on something without first asking a question?

Tags: feature-request, rules

I keep coming across bits of information throughout the internet and every so often, I collect enough data to do a solid write-up on that topic.

It'd be nice if I could post that consolidated info in a place like StackExchange, but it looks like it'd break with the Q&A format.

Is there another community where guides would be better housed?

Comment: I think this stuff is what that little *"Answer your own question"* checkbox on the *"Ask Question"* page is for. But use responsibly, of course.

Comment: See also: [How to share knowledge that isn't an answer to a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238654/21960)

Comment: See also: [Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/21960)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Stack Exchange sites have blogs. Those would probably be a good fit for this kind of thing, but you should check with the users who are running that site's blog to confirm.